# Rotate an object in image about its centroid

Tags: image-processing, image, rotation

I want to rotate an object in a image about its centroid.
here is my code but the result is not as expected. Normally the centroid of the object does not change, except the case when the object is very close to the edge of the image.

[image]

```
edge = MorphologicalPerimeter[img] // DeleteSmallComponents;

center = Round[ComponentMeasurements[edge, "Centroid"][[1, 2]]] 
(*we can use directly the image instead of the edge.*)
im2 = ImageForwardTransformation[img,N[RotationMatrix[90 Degree].(# - center)] &,
                                 DataRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those damn coordinate systems! :)

You can see a small part of the object at the lower left corner of your result image. That's because you forgot to add the center vector after the rotation to translate it to the right position:

```
i = ImageForwardTransformation[img, center + RotationMatrix[Pi/2].(# - center) &, 
                               DataRange -> Full]
```

or better still:

```
i = ImageForwardTransformation[img, RotationTransform[Pi/2, center], DataRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ColorCombine[{img, i}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

As a simple application, let's rotate the center component (only) in the following image:

```
img = Binarize@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SYJS.png"
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cms = ComponentMeasurements[img, {"Centroid", "Mask"}];
centerComp = SortBy[cms, Norm[ImageDimensions@img /2 - #[[2, 1]]] &][[1, 1]];
{center, mask} = (centerComp /. cms);
ir = ImageForwardTransformation[Image[mask], RotationTransform[Pi/2, center], 
                                DataRange -> Full];
ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[img, ColorNegate@Image@mask], ir]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Funny.When the `MorphologicalTransform[pic//Binarize,RotationTransform[Pi/2,1/.ComponentMeasurements[pic,"Centroid"]]]` comes to me.

Comment: @yode Does that work?

Comment: As your second case,I give my solution with **Image-Tools**  to select the component that we wanna rotate following.

Answer (score 2):

As the @Dr. belisarius edited his answer just now,I wanna post a method to solve it about his second case.

First,Use the **Image-Tools** to select one or more components to transform

[image]

Then **Copy as Marker Image**.We get
[image]

Hightligt the components we selected

```
img = Binarize@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SYJS.png";
part = GeodesicDilation[Image[#], img] & /@ 
   Values[ComponentMeasurements[imgtoolmask, "Mask"]];
HighlightImage[img, ImageAdd[part]]
```

[image]

Then rotate it.

```
partrote = 
  ImageForwardTransformation[#, 
     RotationTransform[Pi/2, 
      1 /. ComponentMeasurements[#, "Centroid"]], 
     DataRange -> Full] & /@ part;
ImageAdd[ImageSubtract[img, Sequence @@ part], Sequence @@ partrote]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Have you seen [**this**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108541/193)? :)